# Flexslider issue: imgs increase in size after switching

Tags: javascript, html, size, flexslider

[View the page here](http://ontargetclients.com/staging/womenscareflorida/about-us/)

I've installed FlexSlider by WooThemes as a simple way to have 3 rotating pictures. For some reason, when the image switches to the next one, the next image becomes huge momentarily then resizes back down. The images height and width are exactly the size of the div so it shouldn't be stretching the image.

**My <*head> code**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

**My html code**

```
<div class="flex-container"><div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
  <img src="http://ontargetclients.com/staging/womenscareflorida/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/1.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="http://ontargetclients.com/staging/womenscareflorida/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/2.jpg" />
</li>
<li>
  <img src="http://ontargetclients.com/staging/womenscareflorida/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/3.jpg" />
</li>
  </ul>
</div></div>
```

Again, you can view the problem [here](http://ontargetclients.com/staging/womenscareflorida/about-us/).
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: just for testing sake have you tried using a newer version of jquery? like 1.9.1?

Comment: i copy pasted your code into jsfiddle. it's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/WstMy/1/

Comment: Since it's working in jsfiddle, that probably means there's something else I've coded that's interfering with flexslider. Do you have any idea what elements may be causing the explosion?

Comment: yeah, i just got it, add `width: 693px;` to your `.flex-container`

Comment: it seems that flexslider takes up 100% width of the whatever div its in. It must be something buggy with floats and taking up the remainder space. Giving `.flex-container` a set width fixed it